# AWS SQS polling

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I don't understand the need to configure short and long polling directly on the queue.
Say I create an sqs queue and I want to check the queue for messages once every hour with java.
Then I just need to create a method annotated with @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000) and in the method I call sqsClient.receiveMessage and that's it.
If I want short polling then I can just reduce the fixedRate to call my method every 5 seconds for example.

I already read:

> waitTimeSeconds(): The duration (in seconds) for which the call waits
> for a message to arrive in the queue before returning.
>
> When passing a value for waitTimeSeconds (maximum of 20 seconds), the
> call will block while there are no messages available in the queue.
> However, if there is a message (or a message comes during that time
> period), it will immediately return with messages.

What is it, another polling configuration within my polling configuration with @Scheduled ? I don't get it. Also the max value is 20 seconds and I really don't need to check my queue that frequently.
So do I just set Receive message wait time to 1 so I get the specificities of long polling (check all servers for messages) and ignore its existence because I don't need it ?
What is the usecase of it ?

Comment: long-polling (20s) is used when you want to constantly poll and get results as fast as possible. You could in theory poll with 0 delay every 0.1s but that creates way too many requests. So instead you start a request that waits for at most 20s and if there's nothing you'll get nothing after 20s and if there's something you'll get a result before the 20s are up. Then you do the next request immediately (infinite loop w/o delay). If you need to check the queue only every hour you wouldn't need a delay, you can simply check what's there but that's only useful if you check > 20s (with @Scheduled)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your requirement is to check for messages every hour, then `waitTimeSeconds()` is **not relevant for you**.

It is normally used in high-volume situations where messages are continuously wanted. For this, a 'consumer' is written that keeps polling the queue. To minimise the number of calls, a Wait Time of up to 20 seconds can be specified.

By specifying a Wait Time it is saying: *"If there are no messages in the queue, wait 20 seconds before providing a response to this API call. However, please return immediately if a message becomes available."*

The use-case would be for a system that wants to respond very quickly when a message enters the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Short polling, is used when 'the client' wants to get/process every message as fast as possible (low latency).
Long polling is used when AWS wait for X seconds, before the poll request returns data. This is rarely used, as it required a timeout to occur before the messages are processed. Theoretically, this may yield higher throughput, but only in scenarios where the queue is fully loaded, which is quite rare.

Comment: `waitTimeSeconds` is not a fixed delay, it's an upper limit. Long polling returns as soon as there is a message. But it has the benefit of stalling the response up to 20s if there is nothing to return, i.e. you get at most 3 empty  responses per minute. With short polling you'll have to wait inbetween polls which effectively reduces the throughput in most cases so it's rarely useful. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html#sqs-long-polling)

Comment: I believe the propper definition is that `waitTimeSeconds`, is the maximum wait time when shot polling, but the minimum time when long polling. 
If you message rate is greater then 1 message/(roundtrip-time), then long polling could may yield higher throughput, as you will be receiving more then 1 message per API call.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html

Comment: short polling is when you set `waitTimeSeconds` to 0. You'll get an immediate response with a chance to miss messages that have already been queued but the response is quick. Can be useful in a large cluster that effectively polls at a high rate but rarely individually. Anything above 0 is considered long polling (though anything but 20 is rare since lower values have mostly downsides). You'll get 1 to MaxNumberOfMessages (1 to 10. Default: 1) as soon as there's a message. More than 1 only happens if you don't keep up and your producer is outpacing you. SQS is never waiting to gather messages